# CSS HTML to replace glyphicon with img

Tags: html, css, spring-boot

[image]

I would like to replace the glyphicon with an img tag.

Currently the drop down is written as below

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>
                            <strong>Desmond</strong>
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></span>
                        </a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li>
                                <div class="navbar-login">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-lg-4">
                                            <p class="text-center">
                                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user icon-size"></span>
                                            </p>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-lg-8">
                                            <p class="text-left"><strong>Desmond Soh</strong></p>
                                            <p class="text-left small">Desmond@mail.com</p>
                                            <p class="text-left">
                                                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-sm">Profile</a>
                                            </p>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                            <li class="divider navbar-login-session-bg"></li>
                            <li class="navbar-login-session-bg">
                                <div class="navbar-login navbar-login-session">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-lg-12">
                                            <p>
                                                <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger btn-block">Logout</a>
                                            </p>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
```

How do i change the line of code to allow an img to fit nicely over the glyphicon? I believe I need a css to render it to a specific size as well. I have tried many ways but to no avail. Please help me thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace the span tag with either a img or div tag:

- Using an IMG tag and href to the preferred image
- Using a DIV tag and CSS background property

Here's an example by replacing the span tag with .glyphicon class:

**HTML**

```
 <div class="imgPlaceholder></div>
```

**CSS**

```
.imgPlaceholder{

    background: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/jGlzr.png') no-repeat 0 0 scroll;
    background-color:#0C0C0C;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
}
```